# Sum array on key - possible or is the array not structured in a good way?

Tags: php, arrays, sum

Have built the following array based on an accounting file and want to create sums from the [trans] subarray for all accounts based on the amount. Looked into array_column but have a feeling the array is not built correctly or in an efficient way for this? Any thoughts/suggestions much appreciated.

//Clarification
Hi! Many thanks. I was probably a bit unclear. For the total population of [trans] I want to sum the amount where the account is the same. So the array above would generate:

[1930] = -150.47-431.63
[5912] = 150.47
etc

```
[#VER] => Array
    (
        [A1] => Array
            (
                [verdatum] => 20150107
                [vertext] => GOOGLE
                [trans] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [account] => 1930
                                [amount] => -150.47
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [account] => 5912
                                [amount] => 150.47
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [account] => 2645
                                [amount] => 37.62
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [account] => 2614
                                [amount] => -37.62
                            )

                    )

            )

        [A2] => Array
            (
                [verdatum] => 20150118
                [vertext] => Post
                [trans] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [account] => 1930
                                [amount] => -431.63
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [account] => 5710
                                [amount] => 345.30
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [account] => 2641
                                [amount] => 86.33
                            )

                    )

            )

)
```

Comment: There are so many ways to do it. Starting from a simple `foreach` and ending with `array_` one liners.

Comment: have you tried any thing to do this so far? as u_mulder mentioned, it's super duplicated in SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simply a foreach loop to acheive your expected sum of amount

```
$temp = array();
$new = array();
foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
  foreach($value["trans"] as $key2=>$value2){
    if(in_array($value2["account"], $temp)){
      $new[$value2["account"]] += $value2["amount"];
    }else {
      $new[$value2["account"]] = $value2["amount"];
      $temp[] = $value2["account"];
    }
  }
}
print_r($new);
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/857342

Output will be

```
 Array
(
  [1930] => -582.1
  [5912] => 150.47
  [2645] => 37.62
  [2614] => -37.62
  [5710] => 345.3
  [2641] => 86.33
)
```

Comment: Hi! Many thanks. I was probably a bit unclear. For the total population of [trans] I want to sum the amount where the account is the same. So the array above would generate:

[1930] = -150.47-431.63
[5912] = 150.47
etc

Comment: Aa yes, nice! Read the code and understand the logic Also tested. Wonderful!

Answer (score 0):

```
$grand_total = 0;
array_walk($my_array['#VER'],function (&$ver) use (&$grand_total){
    $ver['total_amount'] = 0;
    foreach($ver['trans'] as $trans){
        $ver['total_amount'] += $trans['amount'];
    }
    $grand_total += $ver['total_amount'];
});
```

So, simply loop through your "VER" then loop again on each trans. As simple as that. I've used both array_walk and foreach techniques, mainly to show you the two ways. You could prefer use two foreach, or two array_walk, it would work.

This script adds to a `$grand_total` variable, and also store the total of all transactions into each `VER` entry.

Comment: Hi! Many thanks. I was probably a bit unclear. Please se clarified description. Want to sum the amounts for each samt account. So an array will be generated for each account.

Answer (score 0):

Modified:

```
$grand_total = 0;
        array_walk($urarr['#VER'],function (&$ver) use (&$grand_total){
            foreach($ver['trans'] as $trans){
                if ($trans['amount'] < 0){
                    $neg += abs($trans['amount']);
                }else{
                    $pos += abs($trans['amount']);
                }
            }
            $diff = ($pos < $neg) ? "-".($neg - $pos) : ($pos - $neg);
            $grand_total += $diff;
        });
    print $grand_total;
```

Comment: Hi! Many thanks. I was probably a bit unclear. Please se clarified description. Want to sum the amounts for each samt account. So an array will be generated for each account.